# django ordered_by reverses distinct

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models, django-views

I edited my previous post, so maybe it is easier to understand:

I have following Models

```
class Course(models.Model):
 name = models.Charfield(max_length=255)

class CourseDay(models.Model):
 course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
 date = models.DateField()
```

For my View, I filter all objects like this:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(models.Q(courseday__date__gt=date_filter) |
                                models.Q(courseday__isnull=True))
```

This gives me all matching courses for the given filter. This may include one course multiple times for each course day matched. The result for a course with 2 days and one with only one day may look like this:

```
<QuerySet [<Course: 5 test>, <Course: 9 Latex>, <Course: 5 test>]>
```

To get ride of the duplicates I use following filter:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(models.Q(courseday__date__gt=date_filter) |
                                models.Q(courseday__isnull=True)).distinct()
```

I get my queryset of courses without any duplicates. Now I want to order this queryset by the date of the related CourseDays.

I have two options. First one is:

```
courses.order_by("courseday__date")
```

Second one is to edit the Course class and add a Meta class.

```
class CourseDay(...):
 ...
 class Meta:
  ordering= ["courseday__date"]
```

Both options sorting the array like I wanted it to do, but if I log my Query Set I become this:

```
<QuerySet [<Course: 5 test>, <Course: 9 Latex>, <Course: 5 test>]>
```

Now if I used distinct or use it on that Query Set, it will not filter duplicates aways. I know I could for example first sort the QS and manually filter all duplicates but it doesn't feel right to me.

Comment: Depending on the database backend, you should be able to pass parameters to distinct, e.g. `.distinct("id")`. [Note from docs regarding your case](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#distinct)

Comment: this results in an Error. Localy I am using sqllite and on production mysql.
Error: DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend

Comment: Worked with Postgres from what I recall, but I am afraid I cannot help you in this case. I hope someone else will know the answer.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, what's the "business" meaning of this sort order? Do you want the earliest date of each course?

Comment: Over all I want a list of all courses of the last 3 months sorted by the first course days date descending.

Comment: Please add sample data and define what are duplicates there for you. Also you can review actual SQL queries being executed in each case. Maybe this will lead you to the solution.

Comment: Edited my post. I hope it get's more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still really don't understand why this is not working. Since I have to go on with my work, I decided on following solution:

To remove the duplicates I will use distinct without only sorting of the query set. For Sorting the QuerySet I converted it into a list and just used to sort function as follows:

```
date_filter = date.today() - relativedelta(months=3)
courses = Course.objects.filter(models.Q(courseday__date__gt=date_filter) |
                                models.Q(courseday__isnull=True)).distinct()
courses = list(courses)
courses.sort(key=lambda x: (x.get_first_date() is None, x.custom_id), reverse=True)
```

It works fine and does what it should do, but still I do not understand why the combination of distinct and orded_by with related fields wont work. Cheers